# Failed to connect to lvmetad in Virtual Box VM

Tags: virtualbox, 18.04

I installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 about a week ago.
Everything was working fine, then I tried to boot it up again a few days ago and I encountered this weird error.

I did all updates as prompted when I first logged in to ubuntu. If relevant, I have boot encryption set up - but I'm entering the correct password.

I'm not sure what this is or what to do. I've tried Googling, but a correct answer to this problem is not clear to me.

I was able to press ALT F3 to access the console.

Would appreciate any help!

This is an image of the exact
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7tTI.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to connect to lvmetad - Stuck on boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969917/failed-to-connect-to-lvmetad-stuck-on-boot)