# Boot problem after update - missing 'lowerdir'

Tags: 18.04

My Ubuntu 18.04 updated last night and now when I boot the system up it shows this message:

```
aufs aufs_fill_super:912:mount[1089]: no arg
overlayfs: missing 'lowerdir'
```

Any clues?

Comment: `aufs` indicates that it is a persistent live system of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Or a severe bug. The corresponding device for the root file system is `cow` in a persistent live system of 18.04 LTS. (And there should be none of those and no overlayfs in an installed system.)

Comment: @sudodus thanks for answering. I'm using a fresh 3 month Ubuntu 18.04 so I don't know what is happening..

Comment: Is it a persistent live system or an installed system? (If you don't know, what a persistent live system is, it is an installed system.)

Comment: If you have more than one kernel in your system, please try to boot into an older one and tell us the result.

Comment: I have this issue after upgrading to 18.04. The GUI doesn't load, but I get a login prompt. I am on kernel 4.15.33 and while trying 4.15.32 I noticed it said giving up waiting for suspend/resume devices before going to the login screen.

Comment: I received this exact error. I cannot boot my system. Recently updated to 18.10. Persistent system with only 13% disk space used. Kernel 4.18.0.

Comment: I have same `dmesg` lines


`[    5.167894] aufs 4.15-20180219`

`[    5.168071] aufs aufs_fill_super:912:mount[1139]: no arg`

`[    5.176827] overlayfs: missing 'lowerdir'`
```
but can login. I am unable to find the config ie there is NO `/etc/systemd/system/mnt-aufs.mount`

Comment: I ended up reinstalling the login manager and that solved the issue for me. I had been following this link for referene : https://support.system76.com/articles/login-loop-ubuntu/

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue. I booted in recovery mode and open the shell prompt. Then discovered that no free space left in my device (with `df` command). So I cleaned up space (menu in recovery mode has this item). And after that, the issue was resolved

Comment: sorry, can't find the df command. could you please elaborate?

Comment: @MycrofD Where did you try to find it? In your terminal?

Comment: yes, tried my terminal, from recovery mode. Nevertheless, deleted some files which when created led to this issue, and could enter the gui mode. Then created a bootable USB and resized the root partition

Answer (score 4):

### Problem

I guess it was after an update when I have had the same issue. In my case it was related to the **Xorg / Nvidia graphics card driver**, I guess. How this is connected to the corresponding error message, still is a mystery to me.

Past the passphrase-prompt for the decryption of the drive, I got the same error message.

```
aufs aufs_fill_super:912:mount[1089]: no arg
overlayfs: missing 'lowerdir'
```

Booting in verbose mode, I noticed an error somewhat like this where it hang:

```
Failed to connect to lvmetad.
Falling back to device scanning.
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg--root: clean, 500699/15081472 files, 9150222/60315648 blocks
```

I tried the following **without success**:

- Freeing diskspace
- rebuilding / updating initramfs and grub
- `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf`: `change use_lvmetad=1` to `use_lvmetad=0`

### Solution:

Booting / login via recovery-mode was still possible so I could make the following changes. If the usual logging-in had not been possible I would have had to make the changes via chroot:

1. I had to change the driver: X.Org-X-Server to the **proprietary NVIDIA driver**
2. Not sure if that was necessary: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-4.15.0-54-generic` (adjust to current version)

res: [Failed to connect to lvmetad - Stuck on boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969917/failed-to-connect-to-lvmetad-stuck-on-boot)

### Info / side-effects:

The driver swap also solved and other odd issue (**gnome-shell high cpu**) that I was experiencing:
My `gnome-shell`-process constantly was using about 30-50% CPU(!) now it is on 1-2%.

Lastly, the **constantly noisy fan**:

There may be a way to manually change the fan-speed (http://www.upubuntu.com/2015/05/how-to-controladjust-gpu-fan-speed-for.html) or you can simply use the integrated GPU.

- `NVIDIA X Server Settings` -> `PRIME Profiles` -> `select Intel`. (You have to logout and login again for this to take effect).

Comment: 18.04 -> 20.04 upgrade. This worked for me. I couldnt get to recovery boot mode maybe because I am using whole disk encryption? I could access the CLI by pressing ctrl+alt+F2 then ran `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

I solved it by removing Docker.

```
snap remove docker
```

Comment: Same here on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Didn't work for me on 21.1

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will be useful for someone ...
On Ubuntu 20.04 after installing lightdm and choosing lightdm and uninstalling reboot displayed also this message. I was unable to log in to the system.
Solution is as always: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery
Mounting disks like described in section: Update Failure.
Then installing again lightdm: *sudo apt-get install lightdm* but choose gdm
And the Ubuntu system booted normally this time.