# Missing 'lowerdir' on boot

Tags: boot

I did not perform any update on my system on Ubuntu 18.04.
On booting the system, I get error

> [24.537547] aufs aufs_fill_super:918:mount[1298]: no arg 
> [24.558603] overlayfs: missing 'lowerdir'

I cannot load GRUB, because I get the same error instead of GRUB loading. So, I cannot boot in recovery mode. Hence, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068588/boot-problem-after-update-missing-lowerdir) does not work.
However, I can access tty, and on running `df`, `/dev/sda1` mounted on `/` uses only 65% of total blocks.
I cannot seem to find a solution, what can I do?