# Linux wont start ( missing lowerdir , failed to rest ppm )

Tags: 20.04

I have a serious error when trying to boot up my ubuntu 20.04. , which wont start... I just get a screen with a few messages on it One of the last things I did before it stopped working was kill a port (8000).

[image]

I was messing with some ports before this happened. I can enter BIOS but not much else... how do I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068588/boot-problem-after-update-missing-lowerdir as you might be out of free disk space.

Comment: 'aufs' and 'overlayfs' tell me that you are running a live or persistent live system. Is it really Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, or maybe some older version (or maybe a 'respin', a Linux distro based on Ubuntu)? I'm asking because I think 20.04 LTS uses `cow`, not `aufs`. Please tell us more details about your operating system.

Comment: Yeah its definitely ubuntu 20... how can i try to free space when i cant get into the os? i dont now anything about BIOS

Comment: Is it an installed system (that you installed from a USB live drive using the intaller)? Or is it a live or persistent live system? The help will depend on your answer.

Comment: installed from usb

Comment: Those error messages in an installed system indicates that it is a problem I have never seen, so I am sorry but cannot help you. Let us hope that someone who knows better will see your question.