# Overlayfs missing lowerdir

Tags: drivers, 20.04

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on my Dell laptop.
I ran the following command to update the drivers
`sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`. After the reboot I have been getting this message on the screen

```
[     6.162177] overlayfs: missing 'lowerdir'
[    63.022235] hdaudio hdaudioC0D2: Unable to configure, disabling
```

I have tried starting in recovery mode and repairing broken packages/ tried to free up space.
The problem still persists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Boot problem after update - missing 'lowerdir'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068588/boot-problem-after-update-missing-lowerdir)

Comment: @Raffa I tried all those options, sadly, it didn't help.

Comment: I am having the same issue and the above link doesn't solve the problem. I am on a brand new server install of 22.04 LTS.