# Ubuntu 18.04 error: you need to load the kernel first

Tags: boot, kernel, uefi

I was trying to fix a 'overlayfs: missing 'lowerdir'' issue very similar to [Boot problem after update - missing 'lowerdir'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068588/boot-problem-after-update-missing-lowerdir).

I removed these packages:

```
linux-aws - Linux kernel for Amazon Web Services (AWS) systems
linux-azure-4.15 - Linux kernel for Microsoft Azure Cloud systems
linux-dell300x - Linux kernel for Dell 300x platforms
linux-gcp-4.15 - Linux kernel for Google Cloud Platform (GCP) systems
linux-oracle - Linux kernel for Oracle Cloud systems
```

and cleaned up the files but then after a reboot, I received this message:

```
error: kernel doesn't support EFI handover
error: your need to load the kernel first
```

Please help, thank you.

**Info**

When I call 'dkpg -l | grep 'linux-image*' I get:

```
ii  linux-image-4.15.0-1129-kvm            4.15.0-1129.134                                 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.15.0-173-generic         4.15.0-173.182                                  amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-4.15.0-191-generic         4.15.0-191.202                                  amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-4.15.0-197-generic         4.15.0-197.208                                  amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-extra-virtual              4.15.0.197.182                                  amd64        Extra drivers for Virtual Linux kernel image
ii  linux-image-generic                    4.15.0.197.182                                  amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-image-kvm                        4.15.0.1129.122                                 amd64        Linux kernel image for virtual systems.
ii  linux-image-virtual                    4.15.0.197.182                                  amd64        Virtual Linux kernel image
```

Comment: "I removed some packages I thought were unnecessary" What were they?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Hi, I edited my original post to include what I removed. I removed linux-image-4.15.0-1129-kvm as well but then I added it back.

Comment: Alright so I managed to solve the 
"error: kernel doesn't support EFI handover
error: your need to load the kernel first" I just removed the kvm package since my system was trying to boot from kvm, still having the "overlayfs: missing 'lowerdir' issue however.