# Ubuntu 18.04 Reboot issue overlayfs: missing 'lowerdir'

Tags: boot, apt, 18.04, grub2, nvidia

Upon rebooting my linux PC, I get this message a couple of times before getting stuck (the [XXXX] are random numbers):

```
aufs aufs_fill_super:912:mount[XXXX]: no arg
overlayfs: missing 'lowerdir'
```

**Context**

I did recently install a GEFORCE GT 710 GPU as well.

**I have tried / checked:**

From this thread: [Boot problem after update - missing 'lowerdir'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068588/boot-problem-after-update-missing-lowerdir)

- Tried booting all older kernels version and all have the same error result
- Tried boot into recovery mode and used **clean, dpkg, & grub**
- Tried freeing diskspace
- Tried rebuilding / updating initramfs
- Tried sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-4.15.0-197-generic
- sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*

**I have not tried:**

1.

```
snap remove docker
```

because I am afraid that might delete unwanted items.

2. "X.Org-X-Server to the proprietary NVIDIA driver" from the thread:

[Failed to connect to lvmetad - Stuck on boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969917/failed-to-connect-to-lvmetad-stuck-on-boot)

because I could not locate the package xorg-xserver-video-all-hwe-18.04. Note: I do not see the error message that was mentioned in [Failed to connect to lvmetad - Stuck on boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969917/failed-to-connect-to-lvmetad-stuck-on-boot):

```
Failed to connect to lvmetad.
Falling back to device scanning.
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg--root: clean, 500699/15081472 files, 9150222/60315648 blocks
```

Please help, thank you!

Comment: Resolved: I did "sudo apt remove snapd"